# Array of pointers which point to themselves

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I found an interesting exercise which says the following:

> Write a type in C containing an array of pointers which point to the type itself

Now I'm not really sure what it refers to.  Does it ask for something like

```
struct a {
    struct *b[];
}   

int main(void) {  
    struct b[20]*;
    for(i=0;i<19;i++)  
        b[i]=&b[i];  
}
```

Can it be written like this ?

Comment: `struct a {struct *a[];}` In C its legal to have pointers to incomplete types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is asking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A
{
    struct A* b[5];
};

int main(void) 
{
    struct A a;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
         a.b[i] = &a;
    return 0;
}
```

Presumably, the point is that a type does not need to be complete, just declared, before you can declare a pointer to it.

Answer (score 4):

No, the exercise is not asking for the pointer to point to itself. It says "the *type* itself". So all it's saying is that the array should contain pointers that point to values of *type* `struct a`. It doesn't matter to which address the pointers actually point.